# Add class to image_tag with if .length > 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add a `class` to my `image_tag`. Without success.

I have already tried several solutions :

```
<%= image_tag (solution.images[0] if solution.images.length > 0), class:"background-image-holder" %>
```

or

```
<%= image_tag (solution.images[0],class:"background-image-holder") if solution.images.length > 0 %>
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What do these snippets produce and why you do not consider that a success?

Comment: Please use English punctuation when writing in English.

Comment: Sorry for my English, I'm learning English at the same time as the code.
Edit my question to correct my English, if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one doesn't work? In this case you have an extra unneeded space there. Try this:

```
 <%= image_tag(solution.images[0],class:"background-image-holder") if solution.images.length > 0 %>
```

Or extract the check, reads better (IMHO)

```
<% if solution.images.length > 0 %>
 <%= image_tag solution.images[0], class:"background-image-holder" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Ok, I'm stupid i always leave a space after the image_tag. Because without the class image_tag does not work without the space.
The second solution works immediately much better.
Thank you

Comment: @ClydeT: yeah, pay attention to your spaces around parentheses :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
<%= image_tag (solution.images[0]), class:"#{solution.images.length} > 0 ? 'background-image-holder' : ''" %>
```

Let me know if it is not working

Comment: It is not working but you can see the answer from @Sergio Tulentsev. Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0):

What about setting the class value based on the `length` condition?

Something like:

`<% tag_class = solution.images.length > 0 ? "background-image-holder" : "" %>
<%= image_tag (solution.images[0], class:tag_class) %>`

Comment: And what happens if `solution.images.length == 0`?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev `tag_class` will be equal to `""`

Comment: And `image_tag` will be called with nil. This either crashes or outputs a useless empty tag. In either case, you probably don't want to do it.

Comment: It is not working but you can see the answer from Sergio Tulentsev. Thanks anyway !